# Is there any way I could get Go to Definition on Visual Studio Code with other extension than .js?

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, go-to-definition

Today I switched some project code base to use Node's ES modules which need to use `.mjs` file extension.

Sadly, this breaks Visual Studio Code's *Go to definition* when an imported resource comes from another module.

Is there any way I can tell Visual Studo Code to work with both `.js` and `.mjs` file extensions to look up for references?

Comment: I've opened an issue too https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35892